# HTML keyup / keydown has a lot of ways to detect key type. Which should I use?

Tags: javascript, html

So when I have `document.onkeyup = (e) => console.log(e);` I get too many options to determine what key is pressed:

```js
 key:"Enter",
 code: "Enter",
 keyCode: 13,
 which: 13,
 charCode: 0, //This is always 0 even when typing "A" or "9"
```

I've been using:

```js
if(ev.key === "Enter" || ev.code === "Enter" || ev.keyCode === 13 || ev.which === 13) //Enter KEY
```

But todo this with EVERY single character (that I decide to keybind) adds up.

Is there a better way to determine each character?
Why is there 4 different options?
Which one would be BEST for overall compatibility?
What is `charCode` used for?

Answer (score 1):

According to Mozilla's [Keyboard Event documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code), here's the list of properties and their status:

```
  Safe |   Not safe    
 ------|--------------- 
  code | charCode      
  key  | keyCode       
       | keyIdentifier 
       | which
```

It looks like they discourage using any form of numeric codes, assuming they are not stable.

My personal favorite is `event.code`, for one reason: the space character is described as `Space`, while the `event.key` for the spacebar is `" "`. Not very readable if you ask me.

That being said, there are certain use cases when I prefer `event.key` though, especially when I only care about alphanumeric characters. It's easier to go with `"a"` or `"7"` (`event.key`) over `"KeyA"` or `"Digit7"` (`event.code`).

To sum up, only `key` and `code` are considered safe (however most of the others *will* work) and `code` is more descriptive, while `key` is easier to work with if you need the keys for actual input.